# How long do I need to be out of Australia in order to reset the 3-month stay under an eVisitor (subclass 651) visa?

Tags: visas, australia

This visa is valid for 1 year and allows the holder to stay in Australia for up to 3 months after which time you MUST leave - but can return for a further stay/s of 3 months while the visa remains valid.

Does anyone know how long you must be outside the country before being eligible to return for another 3 months period? Would it be within the rules, for example, to book a return flight to the nearest country - and come back, more or less immediately?

Nowhere in the regulations governing these visas can I find reference to the duration of time to be spent outside the country before a further 3 months visit can commence.

Comment: This page [eVisitor Visa 651 for Australia (UK Citizens)](https://auvisa.org/uk/evisitor-visa-australia/) says *"The multiple entry option characterizing evisitor visas for Australia means that UK evisitor holders can leave and re-enter Australia multiple times, also **visiting neighbouring countries** or UK in between, as long as the evisitor pass is still valid."* This does imply that if you make a short trip to, say East Timor, then you will be allowed to return immediately.

Comment: @WeatherVane, if you think this answers the question post as an answer.

Comment: @Willeke I am not sure, the extract is just a hint rather than a definite claim.

Comment: The official site says on the [eligibility page for that visa](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/evisitor-651#Eligibility) `Be a genuine visitor
You must only intend to:
stay temporarily in Australia (…)`. Nothing quantified, but I would doubt 4 3-months visits in a row would be acceptable for instance. If the goal is just to stay a total of 4 months for instance, or if there are visits to other countries which realistically do not seem to be just visa runs, I would suppose that would be OK. But aren’t there other visas allowing longer stays?

Comment: Also, what’s your citizenship, how long in total do you intend to stay, what are you planning to do while there, what’s your source of income, and how old are you? This may make it easier to find eventual more appropriate visas.

Comment: @WeatherVane be aware that the page you linked to is not an official site. While some of those sites have quite accurate information, others have a tendency to oversell. No idea of the quality of the information on that one.

Comment: @jcaron that's another reason I did not post an answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing in the regulations that require a minimum time out of Australia before re-entry - you can theoretically re-enter the following day.

However, as jcaron noted, one for the criteria for granting the visa is that you are a "genuine temporary entrant". Furthermore, under subregulation 2.43(1) of the [*Migration Regulations 1994*](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2022C01032) your visa can be cancelled if:

> (ka)  in the case of a holder of a Subclass 651 (eVisitor) visa—that, despite the grant of the visa, the Minister is satisfied that the visa holder did not have, at the time of the grant of the visa, or has ceased to have, an intention only to stay in, or visit, Australia temporarily for the tourism or business purposes for which the visa was granted;

If you return to Australia shortly after leaving following a maximum 3 month stay, the immigration officer may suspect that you are not, in fact, visiting Australia temporarily and therefore cancel your visa.

If you wish to stay longer than the 3-month stay period available on a eVisitor visa, you may wish to consider applying for a [Visitor (subclass 600) visa](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/visitor-600), which allows for stays of up to 12 months.